# OpenCV matrix multiplication assertion

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm getting

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2)) in gemm, file /build/buildd
/opencv-2.4.9+dfsg/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 711
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.9+dfsg/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:711: error: (-215) type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == 
CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2) in function gemm
```

I'd like to know where in the docs it's mentioned matrix multiplication is supported solely for floating point matrices? I could only find people telling this in SO, but nothing so far comparable to a standard documentation.

Comment: please do, what the error hints at, and check the *exact* type of your input, e.g,  CV_64F(6) != CV_32F(5)

Comment: @berak thanks, you made me check that and I realized there's a bug in the code indeed, at one time one of the matrix types gets unexpected. Despite this, I'd like more information about this I've asked, which is unrelated although useful.

Comment: I don't know if this is sufficient, but the documentation for [gemm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#gemm) does state that only float types are accepted.

Comment: @beaker thanks, I think that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned the operator you are using but you can try mat1.mul(mat2), mat1*mat2, multiply(mat1, mat2, dst) or do:

```
mat1.convertTo(mat1, CV_32FC1);
mat2.convertTo(mat2, CV_32FC1);
```

and if needed:

```
mat1.convertTo(mat1, CV_8UC1);
mat2.convertTo(mat2, CV_8UC1);
```

Comment: I'm using `*`. In this question I'm solely interested in docs backing that information or not, since it's referred in other SO answers. I've already solved my bug.